# std::future: Async single producer + any number of consumers problem

Tags: c++, multithreading, future

I want to model a problem where one asynchronous operation produces some `T` and then there are multiple calls to get that `T` on various threads. These calls will be repeated often, so even on one thread, that `T` will be requested multiple times.

I first thought about using `std::promise` / `std::future` for this, i.e.,

```
// Declaration
std::promise<T> p;
std::future<T> f = p.get_future();

// Producer code (different function)
p.set_value(...);

// Consumer code (different function; will be called repeatedly from different threads)
return f.get();
```

The problem here is that obivously `future::get` is a one-shot operation which cannot be repeated, so I thought about `shared_future::get()`. But `shared_future` mentions in its documentation:

> Access to the same shared state from multiple threads is safe if each
> thread does it through its own copy of a shared_future object.

This seems weird, as `shared_future` only has const methods, which should always be thread-safe, so I don't see any necessity for this `own copy` requirement. I don't know how many threads there will be, so I cannot create one `shared_future` per thread. The consumer code can be called repeatedly on any thread. What is the best way to do this?

Can I just create a `shared_future` copy on the fly whenever somebody wants to consume the `T`? I.e.:

```
// Declaration
std::promise<T> p;
std::shared_future<T> f = p.get_future();

// Producer code (different function)
p.set_value(...);

// Consumer code (different function; will be called repeatedly from different threads)
std::shared_future<T> fCopy = f; // Make a private copy of f on the stack.
return fCopy.get(); // Use the copy to get the T
```

Is this how it should be done? Is copy-constructing `shared_future` thread-safe? Will this have good performance, or should I do it differently?

Comment: "*However, I don't know how many threads there will be, so I cannot create one shared_future per thread.*" Um, why not? At some point, a thread that consumes the value will have to be given *something*, yes? Why can't that something be a `shared_future`?

Comment: @NicolBolas: The code is in a component that doesn't know about threads. It just knows that it will be called concurrently from multiple threads. What the threads are given is a reference to that component; but that component is the same for all threads.

Comment: If some piece of code is given a reference to that data, then that code is inherently thread-unsafe (since threading it means accessing the same data from multiple places without any inter-thread sync). So it needs to be wrapped in something thread-safe. Exactly how to do that will depend on exactly how it works.

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course, yes. And that thread-safe thing into which things need to be wrapped is - supposedly - shared_future; especially, its `get` method is `const` and therefore supposed to be thread safe. The documentation tells that shared_future is thread-safe in some sense, but it is not good at telling how exactly to use it that way.

Comment: If you want a single-producer (multi-producer really, but you don't need that), multi-consumer queue in c++, I recommend [this one](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue).  It's header-only, and has forms you can block on, or not.  I can't help with your `shared_future` problem, but this entire question is somewhat of an X/Y problem, and that queue I linked will solve it.  And no, I'm not the author of that code, but I have used it, and like it.

Comment: @KevinAnderson: I don't need a queue. The item being produced is just one single item, not multiple ones. And the "consumers" don't really consume it, they just use it.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for my wrong suggestion in the comment replies, but I think what you want is a [`std::latch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/latch).  Initialize to 1, and have anything waiting on it call the `wait()` method to wait forever until it gets made, or `try_wait()` if you don't want a forever wait.

Here's where I'm coming from:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::latch mylatch{ 1 };
    std::unique_ptr<int> common_source{};
    std::mutex sync_cout{};

    auto myTester = [&]() {
        mylatch.wait();
        std::lock_guard locker{ sync_cout };
        cout << "Through the latch, value is: " << *common_source << endl;
    };

    // Start the waiting threads
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::thread mythread{ myTester };
        threads.push_back(std::move(mythread));
    }

    cout << "Threads started" << endl;

    common_source = std::make_unique<int>(15);
    mylatch.count_down();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    {
        std::lock_guard locker{ sync_cout };
        cout << "After count_down, starting a fresh thread to show it is let through" << endl;
    }
    {
        std::thread mythread{ myTester };
        threads.push_back(std::move(mythread));
    }

    // Wait for the threads to finish
    for (auto& curThread : threads)
    {
        curThread.join();
    }
    cout << "All threads down" << endl;
}
```

Adapt as you see fit.  Change the `unique_ptr` to whatever type you want to distribute, and obviously lock for copying it, rather than just outputting a number.  And if for some reason a "handler" comes in late (after it's already counted down) it's just let through, just as you'd want, rather than waiting forever, as I show in my example.

Answer (score 0):

By default, any function defined in the C++ standard library is considered to be thread-safe relative to some object if that function takes that object by pointer/reference to a `const` object. `shared_future` has a copy constructor, and it takes the reference by `const`. As such, the copy constructor of a `shared_future` is thread-safe relative to the `shared_future` it is being copied from, so long as all of the other operations on that `shared_future` are also thread-safe.

So as long as you don't do anything thread-unsafe to a `shared_future` instance, you can make a local copy of that instance from any thread.

Comment: Then why do I have to copy the `shared_future` in the first place? Because the `get` method I want to call on it is also `const` and therefore thread-safe. Actually *all* methods of `shared_future` are `const`, so they should all be thread-safe. Therefore, I don't understand the following sentence from the documentation: "Access to the same shared state from multiple threads is safe if each thread does it through its own copy of a shared_future object." Why does every thread need an own copy, if all methods of that class are `const` anyway?

Comment: @gexicide: "*Then why do I have to copy the shared_future in the first place?*" Who said that you "have to"? That was *your* idea, remember? `shared_future::get` is `const`, while `future::get` is *not*. There's a reason for that.